# Guidewire : Tomcat server log rotation

Tags: tomcat, guidewire

We have been trying to implement log rotation in Guidewire version 6 for Tomcat server logs. But we dont have any idea and what are the thing require to implment. So could you please help how to implement log rotation for tomcat servers in guidewire version 6?

Comment: is Guidewire v6 alive?

Answer (score 2):

Log4J should be able to do log rotation for you if you configure it properly. The official documentation has some examples for configuring it under Tomcat:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

After Log4J is working with your Tomcat installation you can find many samples for setting `RollingFileAppender` with different properties, like file size, date-time, etc.

https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-rolling-file-appender/

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if it's working. Thank you!